# Resolving multiple instances of interface implementation using Dry IOC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I have a scenario where there are multiple classes that implement the same interface. the consuming class is to get all the interface implementations as a list so that it can invoke method on all the instances.

```cs
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void Do();
}

public class Dance : IDoSomething
{
    public void Do() { }
}

public class Eat : IDoSomething
{
    public void Do() { }
}


public class Person
{
    public Person(IEnumerable<IDoSomething> actions)
    {
        foreach (IDoSomething ds in actions)
        {
            ds.Do();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I register the types so that class Person can resolve all the types that implement `IDoSomething`. This was possible with Unity, MEF and Spring.NET IOC containers. Trying to do the same with Dry IOC.

Comment: Not sure about DryIoC but .NET Core IoC was able to resolve it out of the box. You just register the services as always 
'services.AddSingleton<DoSomething>()'
and leave the **IEnumerable** in constructor. Did you try it?

Comment: I am using Dry IOC with Prism framework

Comment: Are you asking how to get all the types in your program that implement that interface?  Or are you asking more about the registration part?

Comment: how to register the types so that the resolution will succeed.

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registration-api ?

Comment: This seems to me a case of RTM: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registering-multiple-implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to register multiple things as usual with the same interface and whatever implementations. Then inject `IEnumerable` of your interface, or you may use any other collection interface implemented by .NET array.

Example:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Register<IDoSomething, Dance>();
container.Register<IDoSomething, Eat>();
container.Register<Person, Person>();
```

For more information, see [the documentation](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registering-multiple-implementations).